# Let $\phi: M \rightarrow N$ and $\psi: N \rightarrow P $ be differentiable applications of differentiable varieties

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, diffeomorphism

Let $\phi: M \rightarrow N$ and $\psi: N \rightarrow P $ be differentiable applications of differentiable varietes. Prove:

a) $(\psi∘\phi)^*=\phi^* ∘ \psi^*$

What I tried:

$(\psi∘\phi)^*(\omega^*)(u)= (\omega^*)(\psi∘\phi(u))^*= \psi^*(\omega^*(\phi(u)))= (\psi^*(\omega^*))(\phi(u))= \psi^*(\phi^*(\omega^*(u))) =\phi^* ∘ \psi^*(\omega^*)(u)$

b) If $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism, then the vector spaces $H^r(M)$ and $H^r(N)$ are isomorphic for all r.

For the b) I know only the definition of diffeomorphism and isomorphism, but I don't know how to "connect" them.

Comment: The member $\psi^*(\omega(\phi(u)))$ doesn't make sense. $\psi^*$ eats dual vectors and $\omega(\phi(u))$ is a scalar. Also $\psi^*(\phi(\omega(\omega(u))))$ doesn't make sense. I think you have an extra $\omega$ in this last one, but even then $\phi$ doesn't eat scalars either.

How the $\omega^*$ differ from the $\omega*$?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz You're right, distraction mistake! they're all $\omega^*$

Comment: Ok but $\omega^*$ (which I think is a $1$-form) eats vectors and spits out scalars, doesn't it? So how do you make sense of $\phi^*(\omega^*(\phi(u)))$?
Also I guess with $\phi(u)$ you mean the pushforward of $u$ along $\phi$, which I think most people would write $\phi_*(u)$, but that is less unclear I guess.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I think I got confused, $u$ I included it because I thought it was a fundamental element for the demonstration...

Comment: Is $H^r$ the derham cohomology?

Comment: Can you say explicitly what are $\omega^*$ and u ?

Comment: @ArcticChar $\omega$ is a differentiable applications of differentiable varietes, and $u$ is a element of $M$. $H^r$ is the De Rham cohomology

Comment: @ArcticChar but $\omega$ and $u$ are elements that I added, and I think that it's wrong

Comment: You will need to tell us what is $\phi^*$. Is it a pullback of functions? Of differential forms?

Comment: @ArcticChar It is a pullback of differential forms

Comment: Okay, can you write down the definition of $\phi^* \omega$, where $\omega$ is a $k$-form?

Comment: @ArcticChar $\phi^*\omega\in\Omega^r(R^n)$ and $\phi^*\omega=\sum_{I}(f_I ∘ \phi)d\phi_I$.

Comment: @ArcticChar $\omega=\sum_{I}f_Idy_I$ and we can also say that $f_I∘ \phi \in F(R^n)$

Comment: Let's use your definition. Did you calculate $(\psi \circ \phi)^*\omega$ and $\phi^* (\psi^* \omega)$? You will need chain rule.

Comment: @ArcticChar no but i suppose so: $(\psi ∘ \phi)^*\omega=(\psi(\phi))^*\omega=\psi^*(\phi^*(\omega))$?

Comment: Note that you need $\phi^* (\psi^* \omega)$ but not $\psi^* (\phi^* \omega)$.

Comment: @ArcticChar at the moment it escapes me how I can invert $\psi$ and $\phi$...

Comment: @ArcticChar Maybe is  $\psi^*(\phi^*(\omega)) =\phi^* ∘ \psi^*(\omega)$ because $\omega$ is not a pullback, so I can take it out... or maybe I am just confused...

Comment: To be honest, if you refuse to do any calculation I am not sure how I can help, as I said it really is a direct application of chain rule. At least try to verify that for a one form....